# Why RegionPlot plots only the first equation?

Tags: plotting, regions

I want to `RegionPlot` three regions, each of them are
$$t_1<t<t_2<0, \quad t<t_1<t_2<0, \quad t_2<t<t_1<0,$$
but it seems that the Mathematica only plots the first one.
Here is the code:

```
chrule = {t -> (T - t1 + t2)/a}
RegionPlot[{t1 < t < t2 < 0, t < t1 < t2 < 0, t2 < t < t1 < 0} //. 
  Join[chrule, {a -> 1.3, T -> -5}], {t1, -10, 10}, {t2, -10, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

In the code, the region is plotted in $t_1-t_2$ plane, with appropriate substitution for $T$ and $a$.
The result is:

[image]

The blue part is indeed the region corresponding to the first element `t1<t<t2<0` in the list. What about the second and the third one?

Comment: Wrap the first argument in `RegionPlot` with `Evaluate`.

Comment: Note that the first argument to `RegionPlot` is `ReplaceRepeated[.., ..]`, not a list of predicates, so it appears as a single expression to be plotted. The is an issue common to plot functions.  In this case, `Evaluate` results in a list of separate expressions to be plotted and so achieves what is desired.